# Link to a course on Data Structure

Tags: python, data-structures

I want to study data structure with python for my upcoming test in 2 days.

I have studied data structure like stack,queue,linked-list,trees,graphs in isolation without any language.
Also, I have learned python very well.

But, I have an exam on  Implementation of data structure with python.

I searched on youtube hoping to get a 6-8 hour freeCodeCamp video but I didn't get.
Neither was there any course from any other channel.

So, please if you know of any course please provide the link for it.

Any please give only the link and no review or description whatsoever.

I don't want the answer to be a chit-chat which would destroy the reputation of stack-overflow.

I would love if the course is 6-8 hours in length and its level be intermediate to advance.
Even if your course doesn't fit in upper mentioned criteria, please do mention the course.
It might prove helpful.

Course from any site will do. Only, condition is it should be free and good content.

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow*. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you want. However i dont know if this a good use of stackoverflow.
https://www.udemy.com/course/python-data-structures-a-to-z/

Comment: Even though the question is closed, I got what I wanted.